# IntelliJ not autocompleting maven dependency

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to follow [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/tutorial-create-a-simple-plan-with-bamboo-java-specs-894743911.html) tutorial.

I've imported the project, which was created via mvn cli, into IntelliJ and it downloaded some stuff.

Unfortunately, the code completion does not seem to work. What might I be missing? This is a freshly installed IntelliJ.

I expect code completion to work here, when I type .

```
Project project() {
        return new Project()
                .name("Continuous Delivery TEST")
                . // Code completion not working
                .key("CDT");
    }
```

Comment: Can you show where exactly you expect autocompletion ?

Comment: Added the code statement

Comment: What happens when you press `ctrl + space` ? Or when you execute the action `completion` using `ctrl+A`

Comment: ctrl + space pops up 'No Suggestions'

Comment: Is the project configured as a Maven / Java project ? Or the file is opened like a regular file ?

Comment: Opened via file => open project and by selecting the pom.xml file

Comment: Also, if I click open 'External Libraries' the bamboo jars are there aswell

Comment: And you can see the `src/main/java` folder marked as `source` ? The folder should be blue by default.
If it's indeed a source folder, my last idea would be to `reimport` the maven project

Comment: Bingo, the code was in src/main and not in src/main/java. Feel free to add is as an answer and I'll accept